# Root Plist settings

Tags: ios, settings, plist

Hi i'm trying to do something like this .. I would have a PSMultiValueSpecifier with 3 options and on the same page i would have a line in witch the client can write something. I try this code

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
    <key>DefaultValue</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>Values</key>
    <array>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>Titles</key>
    <array>
        <string>One</string>
        <string>Two</string>
 <string>three</string>
      <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Custom Server</string>
                <key>Key</key>
                <string>CustomRemoteEndpoint</string>
                <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
                <string>No</string>
            </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Server</string>
    <key>Key</key>
    <string>MandatoryInputsStrategy</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.